# Creating an Instead of Insert trigger that blocks certain values in AW Database?

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL so apologies if I wrote anything wrong but I'd like to create an INSTEAD OF trigger for the Person.Address table in AdventureWorks so that anytime someone inserts a value that does not begin with a number in AddressLine1 column, it returns a message "Invalid, value must contain numbers".

Can someone please write the code for this? thanks.

This is what I managed to write but it's still accepting addresses without numbers in AddressLine1 column, what did I do wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_PersonAddress_AfterInsert
ON Person.Address
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT AddressLine1 FROM Person.Address
WHERE AddressLine1 LIKE '[0-9]%')
INSERT INTO Person.[Address] (AddressID,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,StateProvinceID,PostalCode,SpatialLocation,rowguid,ModifiedDate)
SELECT AddressID,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,StateProvinceID,PostalCode,SpatialLocation,rowguid,ModifiedDate
FROM inserted
ELSE
PRINT 'Invalid must contain numbers'
END;
```

Comment: I think `[0-9]%` checks for 1 digit at the start of the address. Did you mean `%[0-9]%`?

Comment: I tried it the way you said Preet but it's still allowing me to insert values that don't contain numbers instead of raising the PRINT message :(

Comment: Sorry Preet, your first suggestion worked when I changed the IF statement to NOT EXISTS instead of EXISTS as you had it posted, thanks, glad it was sorted in the end :) have a good weekend !

Answer (score 0):

Her is a code that I use for my site so people have to have 3 did gets followed by 3 to 9 characters:

```
^[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{3,9}$
```

To break it down:

```
^ is an opener
[0-9] tells it to accept numbers 0-9
{3} advises to accept 3 numbers of the previous statement [0-9]
[A-Za-z] tells it to accept letters A-Z in caps and a-z in lowercase
{3,9} tells it  to accept 3 to 9 letters from the previous statement
$ is a closer
```

You would need something like:

```
 ^[0-9]{1,5}[A-Za-z]{1,20}$
```

This will allow 1 to 5 didgets and 1 to 20 charicters with no spaces Ex: 1A or 12345Abcdefghijklmnop

To make it all numbers try:

```
^[0-9]{1-10}$
```

This will allow numbers 1-9 and 1-10 numbers total Ex: 1 or 12 or 123 or 1234 or 12345 or 123456 or 1234567 or 12345678 or 123456789 or 1234567890
Let me know if I can help any more

Comment: Sorry, you confused me a bit, so where exactly in the code should I add this ? ---> ^[0-9]{1-10}$

Comment: I dont know for sure, but I know it works... I use it on a pre coded part of my website... I would guess WHERE AddressLine1 LIKE ^[0-9]{1-10}$) without quotations